# undefined reference : full specialization of a templated member function within a templated class

Tags: c++

All the template class definition is in the header file.

```
template <typename X> class A {
public:

    template <typename Option> Option get_option(error& error) const;
};

template<> template<> Option1 A<Class1>::get_option<Option1>(error& error) const{ return something ...}

template<> template<> Option2 A<Class1>::get_option<Option2>(error& error) const{ return something ...}

template<> template<> Option3 A<Class1>::get_option<Option3>(error& error) const{ return something ...}
```

No compilation error. But, during linking

> In function '`Option1 A<Class1>::get_option<Option1>(error&)`':
>   undefined reference to '`Option1 A<Class1>::get_option<Option1>(error&)`'

And so on for all the full specialization based on ClassN,OptionM combination.

Comment: A full explicit specialization should either be marked `inline` or defined in a *.cpp file.  I don't think this explains your error, though.

Comment: Works as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/801b11de29becc51), but indeed, if in header, `inline` would be required.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both with the inline directive in the header file, or without in the cpp file, i works.